# I am not able to compile with MPI compiler with C++

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, mpi

I was trying to compile a very simple MPI hello_world:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int numprocs, rank, namelen;
    char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name, &namelen);

    printf("Process %d on %s out of %d\n", rank, processor_name, numprocs);

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

And got the following problem:

```
    Catastrophic error: could not set locale "" to allow processing of multibyte characters
```

I really don't know how to figure it out.

Comment: Does the error message give a filename and/or line number?  Does your source file have non-ASCII characters in it?  Is your source file encoded in UTF-16?

Comment: Is that compiler error? Which line does it come from? Or is it runtime error, presumably generated by `MPI_Get_processor_name`, since that's the only one handling strings? Does it disappear if you remove string stuff?

Comment: You're on Mac OSX? They had an issue with locales being unavailable, IIRC

Comment: You've shown all your code, but not your commands and not your full output.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try defining environment variables

```
LANG=en_US.utf8
LC_ALL=en_US.utf8
```

Assuming you're on unix, also try `man locale` and `locale -a` at command line, and google for ["utf locale"](http://google.com/search?q=utf%20locale) and similar searches.

Comment: Yes, That is the problem. The issue is my computer LANG=UTF-8 and when I ssh to the remote server, the server's LANG changed!!!

Comment: @user1819905, `UTF-8` is not a valid language specification. It should be something like `en_US.UTF-8` or `de_DE.UTF-8`. And yes, it could be propagated to the server environment over SSH if the SSH client is configured to do so. The SSH client in 10.7+ is.

Comment: This works for me. Seems that I have different UTF encoding between my local machine and the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

Re-defining the environment variable LANG solved the problem for me, as pointed out (setting LANG=en_US.utf8).

I may say that I'm conecting to a foreign server, and there's where I get the problem compiling code with Intel compilers.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30252743)